# What is the solution for the error when I deploy pubsub for PHP with App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I was working on google Pubsub with App Engine, to get notifications from google play about InApp subscriptions status.

When I deploy my app with the command "gcloud app deploy", error message comes:

**ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [/home/testaccount/php-docs-samples/pubsub/app/app.yaml]
Unable to assign value 'pubsub.js' to attribute 'url':
Value 'pubsub.js' for url does not match expression '^(?:(?!^)/.*|..*|((.).*(?!$).)$'
in "/home/testaccount/php-docs-samples/pubsub/app/app.yaml", line 6, column 8**

My app.yaml file:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: pubsub.js
  static_files: pubsub.js
- url: /.*
  script: index.php

env_variables:
  GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID: "testproject"
```

I have followed the insturctions in the linl:
[Writing and Responding to Pub/Sub Messages](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages)

I did not modify app.yaml file, I do not know what is going on? I tried to deploy "Hello, World!" for PHP on App Engine" exmaple and it worked.

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week searching about why I get HTTP error 500 (Internal Server Error) when I browse **https://testproject.uc.r.appspot.com/**, I got the reason, it was from app.yaml file, all errors came from php version.

Old app.yaml:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /pubsub.js
  static_files: pubsub.js
  upload: pubsub.js
- url: /.*
  script: index.php

env_variables:
  GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID: "testproject"
```

New app.yaml:

```
runtime: php72

handlers:
- url: /pubsub.js
  static_files: pubsub.js
  upload: pubsub.js
- url: /.*
  script: auto

env_variables:
  GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID: "testproject"
```

Thank God.

Answer (score 1):

url should start with a slash.  Try:

```
- url: /pubsub.js
  static_files: pubsub.js
```

Comment: Hi GAEfan, Thank you.
I deployed the application, but when I visit the link:testproject.uc.r.appspot.com
I get **HTTP ERROR 500**.

Comment: Go to your GCP developer console to check the logs.  It will help you find the problem in your code.